# How do I refresh dynamic content loaded into a web part inside my existing Javacscript / jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code that I've pasted below, helpfully supplied by another Stackoverflow member. I've added this code into a Kentico web part, and set the cache `minutes=0`, thinking that would solve my caching issue. It does, but not in IE. Is there any way I can tweak this code to refresh the content when the user comes to the page, or when we have to update the html file?

```
// article footer
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
    var today = new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth(),this.getDate());
    var dayOfYear = ((today - onejan +1)/86400000);
    return Math.ceil(dayOfYear/7)
};

jQuery(function(){
    //Quotes/Testimonials
    var today = new Date();
    var weekno = today.getWeek();
    jQuery('#quotes-wrapper').load('/quotesroller.html div.quote-'+weekno);         
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a cachebust parameter. Since it's a GET request, IE is annoying and always caches the contents.

```
var time = (new Date()).getTime();
jQuery('#quotes-wrapper').load('/quotesroller.html?_cb=' + time + ' div.quote-'+weekno);
```

Comment: I'd be happy to accept your answer faster but I'm multi-tasking ;-). I did try your answer, but my web part doesn't seem to like it. I'll play with it some more.

Comment: Actually, your code isn't playing nicely with my web part. Maybe it's the syntax.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks for the head's up!

Comment: So, I'm answering this one myself because it may come up for somebody else...and it's good to share: I was working in IKentico 5.5. In Kentico, the web parts have caching controls that you can set individually. So my problems was solved, in part, by using these controls. And by understanding that no matter what, some browsers won't let go of their cache...so we need to make sure our Quotes are tested everywhere before putting them up.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to use a more complex function like `$.ajax()` if you want to control caching on a per-request basis. Or, if you just want to turn it off for everything, put this at the top of your script:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

EDIT: To set up no cache just for this request, replace your load with this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/quotesroller.html div.quote-'+weekno, //that's based on your URL above
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        jQuery('#quotes-wrapper').html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @mattytommo, I don't think I can turn it off for everything because it exists on our Masterpage - there are static elements that should be cached.

Comment: @user887961 that's fine, you can just change your `.load` to use a `.ajax` call and then set `cache: false` just on this ajax call, everything is will cache as it already would have

Comment: so, would I contain everything in $.ajaxSetup, instead of the jQuery function? Sorry, confused.

Comment: Check my edit, you use `$.ajax` for an individual call, replace your `load` with that.

Comment: The cache:false basically does exactly what I suggested, by the way; from the jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) "Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL"

Comment: @jvenema ah I didn't know that, I suppose personally I'd prefer to let jQuery worry about it than have to write my own :)